# How to find out in which OS a binary was compiled with terminal?

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, terminal, operating-system

My application needs to know if a binary was compiled in Mac OS X 10.9 or in an inferior version, like 10.6.8. I don't know if there's a C/Objective-C command which can give me that information, but I'm pretty sure that there is a terminal command which can do this.

Someone have any clue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would that be of interest? If you like to know the dependencies there might be a `ldd` command on OSX.

Comment: `otool -l` will give you deployment target version, the SDK used and version of linked libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Your question leaves unclear what exactly you're trying to figure out. The actual OS is irrelevant, but ever since [OSX 10.6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Snow_Leopard#64-bit_architecture), 64 bit has been standard. Maybe you want to know which architecture(s) the binary was compiled with (e.g. for the `ls` binary):

```
> lipo -info /bin/ls 
Non-fat file: /bin/ls is architecture: x86_64
```

Comment: I don't know if the OS is the reason in fact, but since Mavericks, old Wineskin ports (apps which can make Windows programs works) don't work anymore, but ports created in Mavericks works like a charm, and I want to know why.

Comment: Ah, no ideas about that, but it may not be a problem with the binaries themselves, which should still work. However, there might be other configuration changes in the port itself which need to be updated.